# Does anyone know what insect species this is?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The insect has an approximate length of 2.5 cm and It was found in Panama, Central America.
It was living hidden between the leaves of a papaya tree (Carica papaya).

[image: the insect from below]

[image: the insect from above]

Comment: it looks like some kind of grasshopper nymph, but I couldn't find anything particularly close to it.

Comment: A better view of the animal's topside would help in the identification; at present, we CAN say order Orthoptera, suborder Ensifera (long-horned grasshoppers AKA katydids and crickets); with four segments in each foot it isn't a member of Grylloidea (most of the "crickets").